# Highchart axis unicode(arabic) titles are inverted in chrome but not in firefox

Tags: google-chrome, unicode, highcharts

Arabic unicode character word is inverted or unordred in Chrome browser but in firefox, safari its okay. I recently found that Chrome has abandoned the SVG Fonts. I did various things but can't help with that. Please Help ....

Issue is in Chrome but not in firefox browser

Thank you

Comment: I was not able to replicate your issue, let run an example: http://jsfiddle.net/tv0scute/. Could you update my code with yours to introduce issue?

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the solution. Google Chrome has removed SVG fonts recently. So in highchart when adding the title you have to set the property,

```
title {
    useHTML: true,     
    text: "Unicode Name"
}
```

----> should set this to prevent the chrome issue

After setting this all will work fine in all browsers